# XMPP client library for java thats not GPL

Tags: java, xmpp

Unfortunately I need something thats not GPL'd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Smack](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/) is distributed under the Apache licence. It's also probably the best XMPP library of them all.

Answer (score 0):

[JabberInJava](http://code.google.com/p/jabberinjava/) is a project hosted at Google code and it is having Apache License v2. Give it a try!

Comment: small + => poor documentation?